# How to create a file in Julia?

Tags: julia

Is there a quick and simple way I can create a new file (whether it be a txt or .jl file) from the REPL or in Julia script? I would usually do something like use the touch command from the terminal (even though that is designed to update the timestamp of when the file was last edited).

It looks like I can use the [`open` function in "create"](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.open) mode but I prefer to not use that syntax.

Comment: It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.234024286.1949022841.1631233456-1690002512.1626695629&_gac=1.118873467.1631243013.Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAr9FjQp8hjie7s2gkeOGuC4H9izpdqrerj3VpLe7e9l0cnTHr_1bsaAmPYEALw_wcB

Comment: How to create a file and checking if a file exists are two completely different things… Not sure why this question was closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out, there is actually a `touch` function in Julia:

```
julia> touch("test.txt")
"test.txt"
```

which similar to the terminal command, is designed to allow you to update the timestamp of when the file was last modified, but if the file does not exist, the touch command will create it for you. You can read more about the [`touch` command in the Julia docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.touch).